# Audio feedback while coding in python?

Tags: python, audio, pycharm, visualization, feedback

does anyone know if there is an addon (in my case for pycharm), that gives you an audio feedback during scripting? (like for blind programmers?)

e.g I type len(s) and it shouts "len" into my headphones?
Or at least during debugging?
Since I am a newbie I'd like to learn programming with all senses possible. I started with games like code CodeCombat and I realized that it helps a lot when I hear what I have coded.

An improvement could be if you could save your own audios to each command, so you can 'hear' good/bad coding, music-like..

Another possibility I'd considered is a 2d graphic with different colors, where you could at least analyze similar codes with one view like a painting.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: possibly tools available on links pointed to by https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14748886